# what does this line of javascript shorthand means?

Tags: javascript

```
x === false ? true: false;
```

what doesn't above JavaScript mean? is it if x is equal to false then set x to true or else set x to false?

Comment: It doesn't set `x` to anything; it returns a `true` or `false` depending on the state of `x`. `x` will not be altered by this statement

Comment: You're missing part of this statement because what you have so far doesn't have an assignment or a logic directive.  As you're shown it, that line by itself does nothing.  It creates a value `true` or `false` that can be used in an assignment or logic statement (which you don't show).

Comment: See `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:`

Comment: This is a ternary operator, consider it a shorthand if/else. [See here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/be21c7hw%28v=vs.94%29.aspx)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi - not quite because it's `===` so if `x` was `null` or any falsey value besides `false`, you'd get a different answer.

Comment: @jfriend00, ah, you're right, it isn't always equivalent. My bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That resolves to `true` if `x` is strictly equal to `false`, and `false` otherwise. No value is set for `x`.

Comment: @noob: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/359509/61470 for a good explanation on strict equality and it's more relaxed counter part.

Answer (score 1):

```
x === false ? true: false;
```

When **x**  is **equal and of the same type(boolean)** **then** the statement is **true** **else** statement is **false**.

Written longhand would be

```
if(x === false){
    return true;
}else{
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's called the ternary operator. Learn more about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/be21c7hw%28v=vs.94%29.aspx)

or in long hand

```
 if (x === false)
 {
   return true;
 }
 else 
 {
    return false;
 }
```